# Simple file transfer

Tags: c, bittorrent, transfer

I want to create an application in C that allows two users to share a file. I'll call the person sending the file the *server* and the receiver the *client*. There are a few requirements:

- The users need no identification, no "login". You could say they are unknown for my application.
- The server selects a file for transfer and gets returned a simple ~10 character ID string/hash that the client can use to retrieve the file.
- The same application is used for both serving and receiving.
- My application must not need dedicated software running on a remote server, unless it's freely available (e.g. bittorrent trackers).

Now this sounds a lot like bittorrent and I am seriously thinking of doing this through bittorrent. I'm not sure how I would do this. Are there any good libraries for torrent creation / seeding / downloading?

Please answer this question by either:

- Posing a viable alternative for bittorrent / other ideas.
- Posting good libraries / snippets / implementations of the bittorrent protocol in C.

Comment: If you're just transferring files between 2 parties, it sounds very little like bittorrent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And an other solution, send the file through an IRC server (like Freenode). I came up with this solution after I had trouble with opening ports with bittorrent.

Answer (score 0):

This does indeed sound like something best done with BitTorrent. Have you had a look at [libbt](http://libbt.sourceforge.net/)? It's not very well documented but does include a sample client, which is btget.c in /src/.

Comment: Yes I have already found it, but I'm still looking for alternatives for two reasons: Bad documentation and GPL.

Answer (score 0):

I have now found this library: [rasterbar libtorrent](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/index.html). It's in C++ but I don't mind (I don't know either that well anyway).

Sharing here for future reference if other people are looking for the same thing as me.

Comment: Nasty. Who dreams up these ridiculous C++ interfaces?